# Function in IE 11 not getting called without alert() inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a function that updates inner html to a `<div>` via AJAX. In IE 11 and Chrome everything works fine, if I have an `alert()` inside the function then pressing this button calls the function and everything works. If I remove the `alert()` the function doesn't seem to be getting called at all.

I can tell this because it shows a loading gif when it's working and it doesn't show that gif at all (even for a second) without the `alert()` inside the function. Also, it does work without the `alert()` *if* I have the developer tools console open. I was reading that usage of console can cause this but I've searched for console everything and I don't see it. I don't recall using it myself either. I only have bootstrap, jQuery, and my index.js file in this project.

Any ideas why the strange behavior? Also, I have other AJAX calls on this page that all works fine. The only difference that I can see is that those AJAX calls aren't inside a a function I made and instead are just part of `$(function() {})`. As I'm typing this I notice I have another function for deleting rows in this grid that isn't working and it's also in a function I created. Those are the only 2 that are inside my functions and not part of `$(function() {})`.

```
function UpdateGrid() {
    // show the refresh gif
    $("#gridLoader").html("<img id='loader' src='/Content/ajax-loader.gif' style='margin-top: 25px;' />");

    //alert("test");

    // because this is in a javascript file we needed a way to get the url from a friendly C# way and using the data-* attributes provides this for us
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#divGrid").data("request-url"),
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function (viewResults) {
        // update the results
        $("#divGrid").html(viewResults);

        // remove the gif loader once we got our data back
        $("#loader").remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Very odd behavior... Any difference if you use `updateGrid` instead of `UpdateGrid`?

Comment: I suspect that the ajax call is so quick that the loader doesn't have time to show. Take a look at wrapping your DOM update in jquery's `.promise().done()`. This will ensure the DOM update completes before moving to your AJAX call.

Comment: And if you use `$("#gridLoader").remove();` instead of `$("#loader").remove();`

Comment: It's not calling the function. In chrome that split second is noticeable so I would think it would be the same in IE. Plus the delete row function doesn't work at all so it's showing the same behavior and it shares the same characteristic as being in it's own function just like this one. Going to try to add them directly into doc ready but would prefer they be separated for readability sake.

Comment: IE is not doing a redraw....Preload the image. Show and hide it instead of adding/removing.

Comment: It's called right away in doc ready and there is a button that calls it when clicked. <input type="button" value="Refresh Grid" class="btn btn-default" id="refreshGrid" />, then in jquery I hook into the click event. So it is working to show the initial data, but nothing after that. I can also tell because it's reading records from a database and if I manually add records and come back to refresh the button I don't see those records displayed.

Comment: The alert shouldn't change that, unless you're having a race condition. If you are having a race condition, it's not being caused by this code alone.

Comment: Most likely whatever you executed before UpdateGrid isn't done by the time you execute UpdateGrid. The fact that it works in other browsers and not IE is just a symptom, and a random occurrence likely due to browser speed. given the right conditions the other browser will likely show the same issue.

Comment: I'm confused on that point. I click a button which calls this function. This function makes an ajax call and when done replaces the html inside this div. Where is the race condition in that situation? I'm newer to web development so I'm not sure how that would cause issues. I've done this all over the place before. What am I missing?

Comment: it may be caching the url...try adding **cache: false** to your ajax request

Comment: That was it Chase! Strange that other ajax calls in this same file that aren't inside their own functions but inside doc ready function doesn't suffer from this issue. Thank you so much!